# Screen config error when connected over Remote Desktop

Tags: anno-1602

I hope some of you might know the really old game called *Anno 1602*.

It is working on my home computer without any problems. Today I tried to connect to it over Windows Remote Desktop and I get the error: "*SetDisplayMode failed. Please check if your windows display is set on 256 colors.*" I know that this is because Anno is a really old game. But as I said, at home it works perfect and now over remote I get this error.

Maybe it is possible to change something in the remote settings with the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I cannot comment on this due to lack of reputation. I believe your issue may lie in `mstsc.exe` painting the screen.

When you can, see what colour depth your screen is set to (32/16). You can then configure the RDP icon to run at that. By default, the highest quality is 32 bit.

Press `Windows` + `R` and enter `mstsc.exe` and hit enter. Select `more options` and then `display`. Change colours to either `24` or `16` and try. Let me know how you go.

Comment: I have tried every option there. but it didn't worked. But i have installed teamviwer and with it it is working perfectly...

Comment: @TheEquah if that's your valid fix for the solution, Mark it as your answer please.